# Make Ubuntu silent, even in expense of decreasing speed

Tags: linux, ubuntu, fan

I have an Intel i3 mini desktop pc, which is used for home server, mainly for Plex. When a user requires certain kind of video transcoding, the machine spins up its fan very loud, instead of it's otherwise really quiet mode.

I am looking for some easy to set up instructions, which allow me to use the machine silently whatever happens on it. I don't care if it can't serve my users well enough (then they have to choose direct streaming for example), my highest priority is to reduce maximum noise, so maximalize fan speed.

What are the common solutions for capping CPU processing power, to not let it overheat to the level which needs intense fan cooling?

The Linux is an Ubuntu 22.04. The machine is a Gigabyte GA-H81N-D2H motherboard +  Intel Core i3-4130 3.4GHz. The case has only the CPU fan.

Comment: gklka, your question is probably best formatted for forums or groups discussions. Check the question guidelines here in stack exchange for some tips. I suggest you to be more specific here, like "how to limit CPU fan speed with X", if that's not been asked before.

Comment: Nobody can give you the "correct" answer for "Are there any common solutions for this?". If I answer "yes" to you it won't be helpful to anybody, even though it's the correct answer. Besides, listing possibilities won't be of good use to others who come here later. Being more specific should greatly increase the quality of the information you get.

Comment: I am sorry that I was not specific enough for you, tried to be as precise as I could. I am looking for tools which cap the CPU processing at the maximum power which does not require noisy cooling. Like forcing it to do nothing for X percent of it's time or whatever is possible.

Answer (score 1):

Video transcoding is **very** CPU intensive. Since your PC is a 2 core (4 threads) full use will be made of its capabilities. Maximum cooling is required and your CPU will run at its maximum temperature.

One possible way of operating, if you have sufficient RAM, would be to run a Virtual Machine which is set up to have only a single core - effectively running your PC at half-speed.

This works for me for some very occasional transcoding (but I have an 8 core, 16 thread PC).

Comment: This is all true and correct but even running only a single core flat-out to transcode a video is still likely to generate enough heat that the fans will ramp up and make more noise....but for roughly twice as long because only half the CPU's processing power is available.  Another alternative is to configure Plex to use the GPU to do the transcode (IIRC the option is called "Enable Hardware Acceleration" or something like that)....but even that will still use a significant amount of the CPU's processing power and the GPU itself will ramp up its fans while its doing the work.

Comment: The only really silent option is to do the transcoding on another (probably more powerful) machine located in another room where silence isn't required.  And/or to pre-emptively transcode videos in the middle of the night when the noise won't bother anyone.   Transcoding is a very computationally-intensive process, there's not really any way of avoiding that - just accept it or work around it.

Comment: I am aware of the CPU requirements of the transcoding. It is not a problem, if the more CPU intensive transcode processes can't run full speed, because operating silently is a priority for me. For example if the machine can handle 720p silently, but not 1080p, then let it be. I don't care.